# SOMETIMES getting NULL values while using IIF condition and javaCast( "null", "" ) in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

In XXX.cfc file.,

```
var SCOPE = structNew();
var result = structNew();
```

```
result['completeDate'] = iif( LEN(SCOPE.inductionKeyInfo.inductionCompleteDate) GT 0, "SCOPE.inductionKeyInfo.inductionCompleteDate", javaCast( "null", "" ) );
```

Sometimes, `result['completeDate']` returns null though  `LEN(SCOPE.inductionKeyInfo.inductionCompleteDate) GT 0` is true.

I found another way of doing it,

```
result['completeDate'] = LEN(SCOPE.inductionKeyInfo.inductionCompleteDate) ? SCOPE.inductionKeyInfo.inductionCompetentDate : javaCast( "null", "" );
```

But wondering which one is the best way of doing it?

Could anyone please help me if you find any issues here?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The second way is 1000x more readable and is how I would do it. The iif function is a remnant if days past and has always sucked imho. You can also declare a struct these days by using var scope = {};

Comment: The ternary operator would be the modern way to go. But, please tell us how are debugging those values and how are you checking them to see if they are returning the values correctly?

Comment: As AndreasRu suggests, check each value.  If I'm getting unexpected results, I'll add a try/catch block, and in the catch, dump all the things I'm checking.  Then I'll know which one doesn't fit my code pattern.